# Should site rules be applied retroactively in order to delete answers?

Tags: discussion

Should site rules be applied retroactively in order to delete answers?

Is there any reason it should be permissable to delete answers after a period of more than 6 months as was done in this case? I feel that blindsiding like that is downright unfriendly. Do other users agree, or not?

Comment: I have generalized your question, so it can be used as a reference in the future. As a side note, your assumptions about why your answer was deleted is wrong.

Comment: Please restore the links so that people can see what this question is about.

Comment: @WayaringStranger: I edited your question so that the body matches the title of the question you picked. If you have another question, feel free to ask it.

Comment: I am not sure that "retroactively" is the right word here. "Retroactively"  could also mean 5 minutes ago. What you probably mean is "should posts be kept for historical reasons, even if a newer rule comes into play that invalidates them?"

Comment: Also, I am certain that the particular case that you mention in the edit history has nothing to do with new rules. The mod that deleted it, did so because the answer was *factually wrong*.

Comment: That's simply untrue. You were just terminally rude in your comments, and are seeking to cover yourself so as to look better. Since that's the brand of 'skepticism' on sale here, I'm gone.

Comment: Not satisfied with answer, or modifications to this question, so leaving site.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I did not delete your answer, as you can see by yourself. Are you in good faith? Sorry if you find my comments rude, but that does not justify doing exactly zero to address them. Asserting I am trying to hide something when your answer has been left alone for months, and I haven't touched it anyways is a pointless aggression. No thanks.

Comment: Image (for the record): http://i.imgur.com/LzRzG.png

Comment: For the record: *I* deleted the answer. I did *not* delete the answer because of applying retroactive rules. I did *not* delete the answer due to metric versus imperial. I *did* add a comment explaining my reasons for deleting the answer. The answer had been shown to be based on false assumptions, but there was clearly no intention to fix it, and no-one had stepped in to do it for many months.

Answer (score 6):

Rules are put in place to maintain the quality of the content on the site. Content that does not match our standards will be removed if deemed necessary.

Part of the reasoning behind this policy is that, otherwise, old content become [broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows), content that does not properly signal what is acceptable behavior on the site.

For example, a lot of content from our private beta, when the presence of citations to back up an answer was still optional, is now long gone. We want our users to understand we deal with high quality answers backed up by robust facts. Since those answer conflicted with that message, and were not of particularly high quality, they were removed from the site.

Removing broken windows is a network-wide policy.

Comment: @Borror0 To add to your answer, removing old content that doesn't meet guidelines is usually a good idea. Otherwise old content can become [a "broken window"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows).

Comment: @AnnaLear: Fair point. Edited my answer to mention this.